# Add animation when hide "LinearLayout" (View.GONE) and show LinearLayout (View.VISIBLE)

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

Sorry for my English... I will try to explain what I want to do. 
I have a project. It can be downloaded at the link:

- https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxhi0uFKK3upcXJjNGtMVkg4TDQ/view?usp=sharing

As you can see the screenshot:

- http://pixs.ru/showimage/Screenshot_9509352_15647059.png

The button "Hide/Show B layout" hides and shows the green container - "B layout". I want add animation top down when the container "B layout" is showing. And the animation from the bottom up when the container is hidden.  Also, I want the blue container "C", gradually fell together with the container "B". And rising smoothly, together with the container "B". Please help me to do it.

Below duplicate my code:

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
View Layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Layout = findViewById(R.id.bLayout);

    final  View  button2  =  findViewById (R.id.button); 
    button2.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener(){

      @Override 
      public void onClick (View v){ 

          if ((Layout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE))
          {  

              Layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          }
          else
          {

            // Animation animFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
            // Layout.setAnimation(animFadeIn);
             Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

          }
      } 
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem. Full lesson and source code can be downloaded here:  [click here](http://gmariotti.blogspot.ru/2013/09/expand-and-collapse-animation.html)

Or use the code below:

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="#FCF"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/color"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text=""
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clickme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="click_here"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/expandable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Слуга: text3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text5" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
    LinearLayout mLinearLayoutHeader;
    ValueAnimator mAnimator;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setTitle("title");

        mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.expandable);
        // mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mLinearLayoutHeader = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header);

        // Add onPreDrawListener
        mLinearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreDraw() {
                        mLinearLayout.getViewTreeObserver()
                                .removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                        mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        final int widthSpec =     View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                                0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                        final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec
                                .makeMeasureSpec(0,
                                        View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                        mLinearLayout.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);

                        mAnimator = slideAnimator(0,
                                mLinearLayout.getMeasuredHeight());
                        return true;
                    }
                });

        mLinearLayoutHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mLinearLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    expand();
                } else {
                    collapse();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void expand() {
        // set Visible
        mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mAnimator.start();
    }

    private void collapse() {
        int finalHeight = mLinearLayout.getHeight();

        ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(finalHeight, 0);

        mAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                // Height=0, but it set visibility to GONE
                mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
            }
        });
        mAnimator.start();
    }

    private ValueAnimator slideAnimator(int start, int end) {

        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);

        animator.addUpdateListener(new     ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                // Update Height
                int value = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = mLinearLayout
                        .getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.height = value;
                mLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
        });
        return animator;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar issue and this is the easiest solution I could find:

```
setVisibility(View.GONE) on the view you wish to hide.
```

And make sure in the xml layout the parent has following attribute:

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily do this by using the [AlphaAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AlphaAnimation.html) class. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262118/android-button-setalpha) is a similar question with an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! but that's not what I need. Such a question, have this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602488/need-help-for-animation-of-views-in-android but I couldn't find...

Answer (score 0):

So I think what you're looking for is how to hook up translate animations to show/hide a view as opposed to just setting the visibility instantly.

Take a look at [Show and hide a View with a slide up/down animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765938/show-and-hide-a-view-with-a-slide-up-down-animation). Instead of just setting the visibility, first you run the translate animations, then add the hooks to show or hide the view after they're finished.

If you find that the bottom view is not moving, jump into your Android developer options and enable "Show layout bounds" then you can see the borders for views (animations don't move the actual view bounds). To get the bottom view to animate as well it will also need an translate animation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But it doesn't work. The animation appears but "B", appears on the block "A". The block "C" is not moving together with the block B. And abruptly falls down or up, After which there is the animation.