# Android: setOnTouchListener after setOnClickListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener, swipe, ontouchlistener

I got swipe up and swipe down for a layout by using setOnTouchListener (For understanding see below images)

**Images**

[image]
[image]

But i want to swipe up and swipe down the layout when clicking on the button not when OnTouchListener. For this i tried almost all examples in the online but i didn't get any solution according to my requirement. So, please help me to make OnTouchListener event when clicking on the button

### My Code

**Activity**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class SwipeUpActivity extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout rlSwipeHolder, rlSwipe1, rlSwipe2;
    private float startY;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_swipe_up);

        rlSwipeHolder = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_swipe_up_holder);
        rlSwipe1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_swipe_up_1);
        rlSwipe2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_swipe_up_2);
        rlSwipe2.setVisibility(View.GONE);



        rlSwipeHolder.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    startY = event.getY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    float endY = event.getY();

                    if (endY < startY) {
                        System.out.println("Move UP");
                        rlSwipeHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        rlSwipe1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        rlSwipe2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        rlSwipeHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        rlSwipe1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        rlSwipe2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }

                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context="com.app.swipeup.SwipeUpActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_swipe_up_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#0000FF"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_swipe_up_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="#585858" >
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_swipe_up_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rl_swipe_up_1"
            android:background="#FE2E2E" >
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit**

Like this [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2gjrhi02rhi0u8x/swipeup.mp4?dl=0) i have to open the layout and close the layout (or swipe up the layout and swipe down the layout) when clicking the button

Comment: Do you mean ? you want to enable and disable swipe up down. when you click on button ?

Comment: @vabhi vab: Yes exactly

Comment: @vabhi vab: i miss understood your above comment. So, i directed you in miss direction. My requirement is: When we clicking on the button we have to swipe up the layout and again clicking on the same button we have to swipe down the layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the exact solution for this, but i'm posting here, because it may help others.

**Answer**

I saw lot of solutions for **setOnTouchListener after setOnClickListener** but i didn't get. So, i followed the animation for layout up and down as discussed in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28028067/3142611)

and i did minute changes to the code as

**Activity**

```
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class SwipeUpActivity extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
    RelativeLayout mRelativeLayoutHeader;
    ValueAnimator mAnimator;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_swipe_up);

        mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.expandable);
        // mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mRelativeLayoutHeader = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.header);

        // Add onPreDrawListener
        mRelativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreDraw() {
                        mRelativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                        mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                        final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                        mRelativeLayout.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
                        mAnimator = slideAnimator(0, mRelativeLayout.getMeasuredHeight());
                        return true;
                    }
                });

        mRelativeLayoutHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mRelativeLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    expand();
                } else {
                    collapse();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void expand() {
        // set Visible
        mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mAnimator.start();
    }

    private void collapse() {
        int finalHeight = mRelativeLayout.getHeight();

        ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(finalHeight, 0);

        mAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                // Height=0, but it set visibility to GONE
                mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
            }
        });
        mAnimator.start();
    }

    private ValueAnimator slideAnimator(int start, int end) {

        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);

        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                // Update Height
                int value = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = mRelativeLayout.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.height = value;
                mRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
        });
        return animator;
    }
}
```

**Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:background="#FCF">
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/expandable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header"
            android:background="#FFF">


        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create object of your onTouchListenr.

```
 OnTouchListener ot = new OnTouchListener(){-------- YOUR CODE ---}
```

on enable button click

```
rlSwipeHolder.setOnTouchListener(ot);
```

on disable button clik

```
 rlSwipeHolder.setOnTouchListener(null);
```

Comment: Hi, i changed the code like https://www.dropbox.com/s/tyi55f6lx5ms7j1/SwipeUpActivity.java but layout is not swipe up or down when clicking

Comment: Take two buttons in your layout android set OnClickListener on both in one button btn1.setOnTouchListener(null); and in second btn2.setOnTouchListener(ot); When you will click on btn1 and then swipe view it will not swipe and after clicking btn2. your view swipe. Take these two buttons outside your swiping rl_swipe_up_1 and rl_swipe_up_2.

Comment: Hi, i think you miss understood my question (I think it's my problem). I implemented as you said in the comment. At that time when clicking on the btn1 i'm not able to swipe and when clicking on btn2 i'm able to swipe. So, it's working as you understood. But my requirement is when we clicking on button (Take only one btn) our layout have to swipe up automatically and we click again on that button, then my layout have to swipe down

Comment: For this you will have to use toggle button or spinner with two options (None,Enable,Disable), or you can also use normal button. Add a button to ur layout. set its text to Enable. set onClick on that button. Now inside onClick() method add this :-  if(btn.getText().toString().equals("Disable")){ view.setOnTouchListener(null); btn.setText("Enable"); } if(btn.getText().toString().equals("Enable"){ view.setOnTouchListener(ot); btn.setText("Disable");}

Comment: Bro you not understood what i'm saying. Check this video once https://www.dropbox.com/s/2gjrhi02rhi0u8x/swipeup.mp4?dl=0. Like this i have to open the layout and close the layout (or swipe up the layout and swipe down the layout) when click the button